# What's the most efficient way to minimise the following non-linear function?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a non-linear functional $Q\!:\!\mathbb{R}^N\!\times\mathbb{R}^N\!\!\to\!\mathbb{R}$ that I want to minimise (or rather, find the local minimum of, within the vicinity of an initial guess).
\begin{align*}
Q(\boldsymbol{\theta}, \boldsymbol{\phi}) \ =\ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{m=1}^{N}\sum_{n\in \mathcal{N}_{\!m}} (\mathbf{x}_{m,n} - \mathbf{x}_{n,m})\!\cdot\!(\mathbf{x}_{m,n} - \mathbf{x}_{n,m})
\end{align*}
where $\boldsymbol{\theta}=[\theta_1\ \theta_2\ ...\ \theta_N]^T$, $\boldsymbol{\phi}=[\phi_1\ \phi_2\ ...\ \phi_N]^T$, $N$ is the total number of vertices of a graph embedded on a surface, and $\mathcal{N}_m$ is the set of global indices ($\textit{i.e.}$ in the range $[1,N]$) of all vertices neighbouring vertex $m$. Further,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}_{m,n}(\theta_m, \phi_m) = \mathbf{x}_m + r_m\mathbf{u}_{mn},
\end{align*}
where $r_m\!\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\ \mathbf{x}_m\!\in\mathbb{R}^3$ are known, and
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{u}_{mn}(\theta_m, \phi_m) \ =\ \frac{(\mathbf{n}_m\!\times\mathbf{d}_{mn})\times\mathbf{n}_m}{\sqrt{(\mathbf{n}_m\!\times\mathbf{d}_{mn})\!\cdot\!(\mathbf{n}_m\!\times\mathbf{d}_{mn})}},
\end{align*}
for known $\mathbf{d}_{mn}\!\in\mathbb{R}^3$, and 
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{n}_m(\theta_m, \phi_m) = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(\theta_m)\sin(\phi_m)\\[0.12cm]
  \sin(\theta_m)\sin(\phi_m)\\[0.12cm]
  \cos(\phi_m)
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

The terms $\mathbf{x}_{n,m}$, $\mathbf{u}_{nm}$, and $\mathbf{n}_n$ are defined in a similar manner, by swapping the indices.

1. Can anyone give me some advice about the most efficient/pragmatic way to solve this problem numerically? Since the whole function is analytic, I can compute both the gradient and the Hessian of $Q$. Therefore is Newton's method the most appropriate for this?
2. Additionally, considering that I have two vectors of unknowns, $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ and $\boldsymbol{\phi}$, do I simply 'stack' $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ on top of $\boldsymbol{\phi}$ and treat it as a $2N$ system of equations with a $2N\!\times\!2N$ Hessian?

Comment: What is $\mathbf{x}_{m,n}$? What is $N_m$? The sums are improperly written.

Comment: $\mathbf{x}_{m,n}$ is as defined in the second equation. $N_m$ can be thought of a the number of neighbours surrounding a vertex $m$, and $N$ is the total number of vertices on a graph embedded on a surface.

Comment: Ideally, symbols are defined *before* they are used. I don't find the question clear at all.

Comment: Then see if the modifications to my post satisfies you now. I honestly think the definitions of the symbols I'd left out are irrelevant to the problem at hand. The important point is that the unknowns of the system, $\theta_m$ and $\phi_m, \forall m\in N$, feature through $\mathbf{n}_m$.

Comment: Okay, the only unknowns are $\theta_m$ and $\phi_m, \forall m\in [1,N]$. The rest of the terms are all known.

Comment: You should not call the vectors of angles $\bf x$ and $\bf y$. The former is already taken. Functions should have inputs. $Q$ and ${\bf x}_{m,n}$ are functions.

Comment: Apologies. Rectified.

Answer (score 1):

This is a highly nonlinear problem so I suggest the use of a convenient solver. Follows a MATHEMATICA script which I hope, models approximately the problem.

```
n = 3;
m = 3;
SeedRandom[1];
R = RandomReal[{1, 2}, n];
Theta = Table[Subscript[theta, k], {k, 1, n}];
Phi = Table[Subscript[phi, k], {k, 1, n}];
X = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {n, 3}];
d = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {n, m, 3}];
vn[theta_, phi_] := {Cos[theta] Sin[phi], Sin[theta] Sin[phi],  Cos[phi]}
u[phi_, theta_, d_] := Cross[Cross[vn[phi, theta], d], vn[phi, theta]]/Sqrt[Cross[vn[phi, theta], d].Cross[vn[phi, theta], d]]
x[i_, j_] := X[[i]] + R[[i]] u[Theta[[i]], Phi[[j]], d[[i, j]]];
Q = Sum[Sum[(x[i, j] - x[j, i]).(x[i, j] - x[j, i]), {j, 1, m}], {i, 1, n}];
vars = Join[Phi, Theta];  
sol = NMinimize[F, vars]
```

You can choose as well an initial point

```
inic = {Table[0, n + m]};
sol = NMinimize[Q, vars, Method -> {"Automatic", "InitialPoints" -> inic}]
```

To calculate the hessian eigenvalues

```
H = Grad[Grad[Q, vars], vars] /. Last[sol] // Eigenvalues
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have very little experience solving non-linear problems like this. Is there a way to get a feel for how non-linear this problem is in the region of my initial guess? That is, is there a way I can know whether or not my initial guess is in the convergence ball of the global minimum? A typical initial guess would be all $\mathbf{n}_m$ being the outward-pointing normal of a sphere, with a slight initial perturbation (less than $15^{\circ}$). Then the final solution I seek, is for all $\mathbf{n}_m$ to be exactly equal to the outward-pointing normal at the vertex.

Comment: It seems to me that the objective function can have many local minimums. The proximity of a local minimum can be detected by analyzing the Hessian at a proposed initial  point.The lack of convexity does not allow us to know in advance, if a local minimum is also the global minimum.

Comment: Okay I see, so would the sign of the determinant of the Hessian be the indicator of the convexity/concavity of the objective function at a given point? Also, as per my second question, am I right to stack the two unknown vectors together, resulting in a $2N\! \times\! 2N$ Hessian?

Comment: Yes. The unknowns should be stacked. For local convexity test, the hessian should have all eigenvalues positive.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much! I'm still a bit confused about computing the Hessian. Am I right in that the terms that go into the Hessian are $\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial\theta_m^2}$, $\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial\theta_m\partial\theta_n}$, $\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial\theta_m\partial\phi_m}\!=\!\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial\phi_m\partial\theta_m}$, $\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial\theta_m\partial\phi_n}\!=\!\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial\phi_m\partial\theta_n}$, $\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial\phi_m^2}$, and $\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial\phi_m\partial\phi_n}$?

Comment: Yes. I included an additional line to calculate the eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks so much for your advice, and the Mathematica script!! :)