# Can anyone verify if the following terms are correct, for a Hessian of a function of 2 unknown vectors?

Tags: optimization, partial-derivative, nonlinear-optimization, hessian-matrix

I have a function $Q\!:\!\mathbb{R}^N\!\times\mathbb{R}^N\!\!\to\!\mathbb{R}$ which takes in as arguments, the vectors $\boldsymbol{\theta}=[\theta_1\ \theta_2\ ...\ \theta_{N}]^T$ and $\boldsymbol{\phi}=[\phi_1\ \phi_2\ ...\ \phi_{N}]^T$. I wish to minimise $Q$ using Newton's method. If I stack $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ on top of $\boldsymbol{\phi}$, the gradient of $Q$ is expressed as $\nabla Q=[\partial Q/\partial \theta_1\ ...\ \partial Q/\partial \theta_{N}\ \partial Q/\partial \phi_1\ ...\ \partial Q/\partial \phi_{N}]^T$. Can anyone verify if the following terms are what I would require, in order to compute the Hessian matrix $\nabla^2 Q$?

$\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial\theta_m^2}$, $\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial\theta_m\partial\theta_n}$, $\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial\theta_m\partial\phi_m}\!=\!\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial\phi_m\partial\theta_m}$, $\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial\theta_m\partial\phi_n}\!=\!\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial\phi_m\partial\theta_n}$, $\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial\phi_m\partial\phi_n}$, and $\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial\phi_m^2}$ for all $m,n\!\in\![1,N]$, and $m\!\neq\! n$.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, looks good to me.
One thing I would suggest for when you're doing this calculation is not to split up the $m=n$ case. Then you just have to calculate:
$\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial\theta_m\partial\theta_n}$,  $\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial\theta_m\partial\phi_n}$, and 
$\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial\phi_m\partial\phi_n}$. These correspond to the upper left, skew-diagonal, and lower right blocks of the Hessian respectively.

Another thing you could look at is using a automatic differentiation library like Tensorflow, PyTorch, or Jax. There's generally no performance penalty for doing so.

Comment: I agree that the 3 terms you've stated is equivalent to my 6 terms 'notationally' when $m\!=\!n$. However, when computing the terms for my problem, they are quite distinct. Here's a link to the problem I am trying to minimise: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3484119. Is it not to be expected that, for instance, $\frac{\partial^2Q}{\partial\theta_m\partial\theta_n}\! \neq\! \frac{\partial^2Q}{\partial\theta_m^2}$ when $n$ is set to equal $m$ 'after' having computed the LHS?

Comment: Fair enough. I'd definitely recommend using an automatic differentiation package like the ones I listed. Also if $N$ is large you might be better off with a first order optimizer, or just computing the diagonal elements of your Hessian. Constructing and inverting a big Hessian can be more work then it's worth.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I plan on using this for a fluid dynamics problem. But on a subset of the vertices in my computational mesh. Relative to the size of the mesh, this particular problem is quite small, so I'm not really worried about the cost. Also, I'll do the Hessian solve iteratively, so I won't need to worry about direct inversion :)